# Pass Class of common superclass to Function; Function should check if an Object is instanceof passed class

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, instanceof

I have different Frames which extend MyFrame stored in an ArrayList

```
abstract public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame(){
        super();
    }
    abstract public void update();
}
```

now I want a function where I pass the ArrayList and a List of Class Types, the function should call update on all Objects of the passed types

```
public void foo(ArrayList<MyFrame> frames, ArrayList<Class> types){
    for(MyFrame f : frames){
        for(Class c : types){
            if(f instanceof c){
                f.update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You ask no question

Comment: well the foo() function doesn't work the way I posted it

Comment: for the line if(f instanceof c) i get error "c cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: So you want to pass a list of objects of subtypes A, B, C and D, and a list of classes A and B, and then you want to call update on each object only if it's of class A or B?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't need to add class to ArrayList but you need to add instance of `MyFrame` to list.

2) And then you can just do something as below

```
public void foo(List<MyFrame> frames){
    for(MyFrame f : frames){
                f.update();
    }
}
```

> Edit based on your comment

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyFrame> myFrameList = new ArrayList<MyFrame>();
        myFrameList.add(new A());
        myFrameList.add(new B());
        foo(myFrameList,A.class);


    }
    public static void foo(List<MyFrame> myFrameList, Class c)
    {
         for(MyFrame f:myFrameList)
        {
            if(c.isInstance(f))
            {
                f.update();
            }
        }
    }
}

abstract class MyFrame
{
     public abstract void update();
}
class A extends MyFrame
{

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Aaaaa");
    }

}

class B extends MyFrame
{

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Bbbb");
    }

}
```

Comment: MyFrame is abstract class. I have different classes that extend MyFrame and only want to update only the Frames of the correct type. I want to pass Class to tell the function which Frames I want to update.

Comment: Even then. The actual instance will be of MyFrame only. So basically if you have class A extends MyFrame and class B extends MyFrame then you can add A and B to List of MyFrame and it will work. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to update only class A though, to save execution time

Comment: Updated my answer @abinmorth as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the problem is that `c` is not a class name; it's a variable that refers to an instance of a `Class` object. Instead of `instanceOf`, use:

```
public void foo(ArrayList<MyFrame> frames, ArrayList<Class> types){
    for(MyFrame f : frames){
        for(Class c : types){
            if(f.getClass() == c){
                f.update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```